# React / Redux - Create XHR request based on state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a method that gets called from a Button click. In this method, I toggle some state between true or false. After I toggle state, I need to make an XHR request to a server with the state I just changed.

```
handleButtonClick = () => {
    //toggle 'in_progress' state attribute to false or true
    this.toggleInProgressState();

    //redux widget state
    const { state } = this.props;

    //Send data to server 
    const data = {};
    data.in_progress = state.in_progress;
    axios.patch(`/api/v1/somewhere}/`, data)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

The issue I am running into is that state the state I send to server is not the actual state of the application. I believe this is most likely because React has not yet finished rendering. How can I go about making sure React is done updating the state before I send my XHR?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, now I saw you're working with Redux. Here you could use the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method and compare the new state with the old state. If it has changed you can make your XHR request. This is when you have matched your redux state to props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.yourState!==this.props.yourState){
    yourXhrRequest();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this.setState is an asynchronous function. Make your xhr request in the callback of this.setState. This way you can work with the changed state.

```
this.setState({someState: someState}, ()=>{
   yourXhrRequest() //Here the state has changed
});
```